# Unique field in cloud kit while syncing with local core data cache

Tags: ios, database, core-data, duplicates, cloud

Am trying to implement cloudkit sync with local core data stack, I had a few doubts as follows

1. I needed a table to have unique field other then the CKRecordID field. So how can i achieve this ?  The manual process of checking before inserting in cloudkit is too cumbersome.
2. Prevent deletion of a parent record if a child record exist in cloud kit. 
   Explanation: Say i have two devices both are synced with cloud with a single child for a parent record, now Device 1 inserts a child record for that parent and syncs with cloud kit and device 2 deletes that particular parent, now when device 2 syncs with cloud it automatically deletes the parent and the new inserted child with it. What i want to achieve is if a new child exist on a parent in cloud then the parent record must not get deleted instead when device 2 syncs, it gets the parent along with new child record.

Note: Using Private database with custom zone.

Any suggestions are most welcome. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you start syncing between **cloud kit** and **core data** start it from parent entities and then sync child entities.

When Device 1 is synced with cloud kit then the child record will be synced.

When Device 2 will sync then before delete from cloud kit to core data, You have to check following scenario :-

1. If Parent deleted from local and it sync with cloud kit then **first check is there any child entity available** of parent’s entity on cloud kit, If available then don’t delete it from local core data.

(Note :- Before delete any parent from cloud kit or core data you have to check first is there any new child available from its opposite side)

Answer (score 0):

You said private database, you should be using CloudKit CoreData that's exactly the scenario it was designed for.

Public database is a different story.

Comment: CloudKit Core Data is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the called to this method to generate your own UUID that you can then use as a record ID.

   let uuid = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, CFUUIDCreate(nil))
2. You need to be creating references that point backwards. So you **wouldn't** put this in a reference filled of the parent RECORD and then create a child with it ;

> You would create the parent with this ID and point the children to it

That way if the parent gets deleted, yes the child does [assuming you choose that option]; but if the child gets deleted the parent remains in place.

Here the some Swift 2.0 code to bring it all together, newRecord here is a CKRecord, theLink is a reference field. This code you would use when you create the child record.

```
uniqReference = NSUUID().UUIDString
let singleLink2LinkthemALL = CKRecordID(recordName: uniqReference)
let theLinkRef = CKReference(recordID: singleLink2LinkthemALL, action: .DeleteSelf)
newRecord2.setObject(theLinkRef, forKey: "theLink")
```

I strongly suspect; I have not tested it that if you had a child record with two backward references to two distinct parent records, it would remain in place even if one of the parents was deleted.